# Vector of unique pointers: Finding and then rotating an element to the front of a vector by pointer

Tags: c++, algorithm, find, c++20, unique-ptr

Suppose I have a `std::vector` of unique pointers to an object.

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct MyObject {

};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject> myObjects;
```

Now suppose that vector is populated with some objects, and I would like to rotate a specific pointer to the front. I attempted using the `find_if` function like this to find a pivot:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void rotate_to_front(MyObject * myobject){
     auto pivot = std::find_if(std::begin(myObjects), std::end(myObjects), [myObject](const MyObject & memberObject){
          return myObject == memberObject;
     });
}
```

But `clang` throws `deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Element'`.

After I find my pivot, I would like to use `std::rotate` to move it to the front.

```cpp
std::rotate(std::begin(myObjects), pivot, pivot + 1);
```

### Notes:

1. Is there a way to do this with `std::find` instead of `std::find_if`? I was unable to get this to work either.

Comment: The vector elements are unique_ptr, not MyObject. The parameter of the lambda should be const unique_ptr& or const auto&.

Comment: @S.M. So the proper way to do this is to use `window == m_Window.get()`?

Comment: Thank you, @S.M. !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `std::find_if()` to compile, the parameter of the lambda must match the object type in the `std::vector`, which is `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>` not `MyObject`, or be implicitly convertible to the argument type, which is not possible in this case. So, the proper way would be:

```
 auto pivot = std::find_if(std::begin(myObjects), std::end(myObjects), 
      [myObject](const std::unique_ptr<MyObject> & memberObject){
           return myObject == memberObject.get();
      });
```

> Is there a way to do this with std::find instead of std::find_if?

For that to work, `std::unique_ptr` has to provide an `operator==` to compare a raw pointer, which is not the case, so no, you have to provide a predicate by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me! Also +1 for @S.M. 's comment.

Comment: It doesn't have to match, it just has to be compatible.  But here, match is true.